# Exporting to CSV dropping off text

Tags: ms-access

I am attempting to export out a concatenated note from a table in a database I'm given and export it out into a CSV file. The below code works getting it to be seen in the Datasheet view. However whenever I export the file to a CSV the Note column is cut off at "Actual Note:" and CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Actual_Notes is not displayed. I'm not sure what could cause this and would like help figuring it out.

One potential thing to consider is that CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Actual_Notes is a long text field while all other fields, except the two date fields, are short text fields. I don't know if that's causing it though.

My only other guess is there a hidden character in the beginning of the Actual Note.

I'd greatly appreciate any insight as to why it might be dropping.

```
SELECT CnBio.CnBio_Import_ID,
CnBio.CnBio_First_Name,
CnBio.CnBio_Last_Name,
CnBio.CnBio_Org_Name,
CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Type AS [Note Type],
Format(CnNote_1.[CnNote_1_Date], 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS [Date],
Format(CnNote_1.[CnNote_1_DateAdded], 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS [Original Date],
IIf(CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Title <> '', "Title: " & CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Title & "      ") & IIf(CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description <> '', "Description: " & CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Description & "      ") & IIf(CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Actual_Notes <> '', "Actual Note: " & replace(replace(CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Actual_Notes, Chr(13), "   "), Chr(10), "   ")) AS Notes
FROM (Cn LEFT JOIN CnBio ON Cn.CnBio_LINK = CnBio.CnBio_LINK) LEFT JOIN CnNote_1 ON Cn.CnNote_1_LINK = CnNote_1.CnNote_1_LINK
```

For more information I'm exporting via MS Access's export using the Text File export. It also occures when exporting out using the Excel unless I select "Export out with formatting and layout."

Comment: Please provide the way you're exporting the query. Exporting it using VBA, Excel and automation can likely fix this.

Comment: I'm exporting via MS Access's export using the Text File export. It also occures when exporting out using the Excel unless I select "Export out with formatting and layout."

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that is the only problem but you are using IIF wrong.

Instead of

```
IIf(CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Title <> '', "Title: " & CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Title & "      ")
```

Use

```
IIf(CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Title <> '', "Title: " & CnNote_1.CnNote_1_Title & "      ", "")
```

All of your IIFs are similarly flawed.